# Can't install Windows 7 gadget

Tags: windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm developing a very simple gadget for Windows 7. I have created an index.html file and a gadget.xml file, compressed them as a zip, changed the extension to gadget.
When I double click on the .gadget file I get a window telling me if I'm sure I want to install the gadget as it comes from an untrusted publisher. I click 'Install', and everything seems to be fine.
However, the gadget is not installed.
I've looked at the Event Viewer and found nothing, it just silently fails.
Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?
Here's the gadget.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gadget>
<name>Elecciones 2011</name>
<namespace>gnuine.com</namespace>
<version>1.0.0.0</version>
<author name="whatever">
    <info url="hiddenforpublicpublish" />
</author>
<copyright>2011</copyright>
<description>Description</description>
<hosts>
    <host name="sidebar">
        <base type="HTML" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="index.html" />
        <platform minPlatformVersion="1.0" />
        <permissions>Full</permissions>
    </host>
</hosts>
</gadget>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a .zip which has all the files directly in it.

What you probably have done is, put index.html and gadget.xml in a folder, zipped the folder.

What really needs to be done is, select index.html, gadget.xml and other files and folder and make a .zip out of it.

This was the issue I had faced, and doing this solved the problem.

Please check if that works.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. download gadget
2. rename to rar extension from gadget extension
3. go to C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets
4. extract all rename files with the same gadget file name like "new.gadget"
5. move the extracted folders to that directory. (to C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets)

now you are done, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the version number, I thought it had to be:

`x.x`

not
`x.x.x.x`